# adding number of miners in an existing ethereum network

Tags: ether

I am using geth and power shell to develop an ethereum network. I have an existing network with 3 nodes where 1 is mining. Now i want to increase number of miner nodes. How can we do it.

Comment: if it's a regular PoW network just connect a new miner and that's it. if it's PoA then you have to somehow manually add the new one

Comment: @LauriPeltonen just miner.start() and that's all ?

Comment: yes, if it's PoW. Remember to set bootnodes correctly so the new node finds the network

Comment: Do you want existing node to mine or do you want to ad new nodes that will mine ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain , i have network of 3 nodes all are synced with each other ( enode info added), and one is mining. Now for this case, in same network i want 2 nodes to mine instead of one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this from the comments:

> @FlorianCastelain , i have network of 3 nodes all are synced with each
>   other ( enode info added), and one is mining. Now for this case, in
>   same network i want 2 nodes to mine instead of one

Say the current mining node is called A, the two others are B and C.

In order to tell the node B to mine, you have two options:

---

**Option A**

If the console is available in your geth node B, you can just run the following command inside it:

```
miner.start(x)
```

Where `x` is the number of threads alocated to mining.

---

**Option B**

You can take the command you use to launch node A and use it to launch node B (adapt it if required).

It should look like something like this:

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=x
```

Where `x` is the number of thread to alocate.

More information here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining